# Downloading multiple JSON files from a website folder

Tags: r, json, httr

I'm trying to download all the files with the word 'tree' from this [link](https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/metadata/published/paleo/json/).

I know how to download them individually, but I can't figure out how to download them all at once, according to that conditions (has word 'tree').

Comment: wget -r "site"  I guess with inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: Could you elaborate sorry? Not familiar with this command :)

Comment: It's not native R but if you're on a *nix system, you could use that. I'm not sure if `download.file` supports recursive downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be very slow(see notes):

```
 library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
my_table<-read_html("https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/metadata/published/paleo/json/")
my_table %>% 
  html_nodes(css="table") %>% 
  html_table() -> res
json_names<-res[[1]][,2]
json_names %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  slice(3:nrow(.)) %>% 
  filter(grepl("tree",value)) %>% 
  pull(value) %>% 
  lapply(.,function(x) paste0("https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/metadata/published/paleo/json/",
                                                x)) %>% 
  unlist() -> url_list
```

Sample results:

```
 lapply(url_list[1:2],jsonlite::fromJSON)
[[1]]
[[1]]$xmlId
[1] "4355"

[[1]]$NOAAStudyId
[1] "2657"

[[1]]$studyName
[1] "Adams - Fernow Experimental Forest - QUPR - ITRDB WV003"

[[1]]$doi
[1] "https://doi.org/10.25921/jzj2-vy39"
```

**NOTE**:

On a *nix machine, I would use `wget` instead.